# net core 2.2 to 3.0 authentication migration AddOpenIdConnect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Currently I'm in upgrading asp net core 2.2 web site to net core 3.0 that uses Identity Server 4 authentication and found issue that stops me to finish this task: In .net core 3.0 there is no **AddOpenIdConnect** method in **OpenIdConnectExtensions** (docs are clear about it:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.openidconnectextensions.addopenidconnect?view=aspnetcore-2.2&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0).)

So is there any substitute in .net core 3.0?

Startup.cs that works in net core 2.2

```
IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                    {
                        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    })
                    .AddCookie(options =>
                    {
                        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                    })
                    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                    {
                        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                        options.Authority = "sso url";
                        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                        options.ClientId = "client_id";
                        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                        options.ResponseType = $"{OpenIdConnectParameterNames.Code} {OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken}";

                        options.SaveTokens = true;
                        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;                    
                    })
```

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6486 ?

Answer (score 17):

If you examine the 2.2 -> 3.0 migration document here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

You will see in the add package references for removed assemblies section (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-package-references-for-removed-assemblies) that there is now a nuget package to support this:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect

Answer (score 2):

For recognizing **AddOpenIdConnect**, from version 3.0 onwards, you must install package:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect
```